# "Failed to register bundle identifier" for my client's project even though I'm on their App Store Connect team

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect, code-signing

I'm working as a freelance iOS developer for a customer's project and I'd like to be able to build the app on my device.

I created a new Apple ID from scratch and sent it to my customer so that they invited me to join their team with "Developer" privileges. We did that successfully: I accepted the invitation and now when I go to check my account on developer.apple.com I can see the company name of my customer right underneath my name.

I added this new account to Xcode and it is marked as a Personal Team. I don't see any mention of my customer's project in Xcode.

[image: Xcode Account preferences for the new Apple ID]

And when I want to compile, I get the classic error message: *"Failed to register bundle identifier. The app identifier "com.xxx.yyy" cannot be registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again."*

[image]

What am I missing here? For Xcode it's like this Apple ID wasn't related in anyway to my customer's project whereas the developer website says it is? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to add the AppID into your client's Developer Account?

Comment: Did they give you access to certificates and identifiers?  If not then someone with that access will need to create the app identifiers for you

Comment: Oh, maybe they didn't indeed. Is there any support page / tutorial I could send them so they're able to do it?